# StanfordNLP for Python3.7

Tags: stanford-nlp, python-3.7

I tried to install StanfordNLP for python 3.7. I refered [this](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/#get-started). But when I typed `pip install stanfordnlp`

It gives some errors.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0 (from stanfordnlp) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)

No matching distribution found for torch>=1.0.0 (from stanfordnlp)
```

Is there any solution for this error?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?  It's a little difficult to diagnose without more information.

However, if you install pytorch on your own, it is likely this problem will go away.